# Find if a List item exists in Dictionary Values and get the Key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I need to find keys from a dictionary that contains values by matching items in a list. My approach is as below...

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,3,4], "b": [3,4,6], 'c': [88,22,1]}
list1 = [1,3]
links = []
dict2 = {}
for key, value in dict1.iteritems():
    for link in list1:
       if link in dict1[key]:
           links.append(link)
           temp = links
           dict2[key]=temp
           links[:]=[]

print dict2
```

The output I want is

```
{'a': [1,3], 'c': 1, 'b': 3}
```

But with the above code I get...

```
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': []}
```

Can somebody please explain where I am going wrong. Any help here will be highly appreciated

Comment: The code in the `for` loop is indented incorrectly. The result depends on how you actually indent the code. Please update your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler implementation:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':[1,3,4], "b": [3,4,6], 'c': [88,22,1]}
>>> list1 = [1,3]
>>> res = {}
>>> for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
...     if any(i in v for i in list1):
...         res[k] = [i for i in v if i in list1]
...
>>> res
{'b': [3], 'c': [1], 'a': [1, 3]}
```

As for your original solution, it has issues with variable scope and indentation. Here is a solution that will work:

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,3,4], "b": [3,4,6], 'c': [88,22,1]}
list1 = [1,3]

dict2 = {}
for key, value in dict1.iteritems():
    links = []
    for link in list1:
        if link in dict1[key]:
           links.append(link)
    dict2[key] = links

print(dict2)
```

Comment: Replace `iteritems()` with `items()` for Python3

Comment: Thank you. I intend to apply this on a crawler I am building. From an efficiency point of view, would this be a better solution for handling dictionary with 1000s of keys and values?

Comment: They will perform pretty much the same. One thing to note is that my solution excludes any keys that don't have matching values--if you don't want that behavior, simply remove the `if any()` line.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,3,4], "b": [3,4,6], 'c': [88,22,1]}
list1 = [1,3]

res = {key : list(set(value) & set(list1)) for key, value in dict1.items()}
```

`set1=set(list1)` can be precomputed for efficiency.

Comment: Very elegant solution!